# Simple Joins not working in H2 Database when giving multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, h2

I have many tables and want to retrieve data with joins in H2 Database but a very simple join is not working when given multiple tables.

```
SELECT a.*, b.name "make", c.name "model"
FROM basicInfo AS a, make_models AS b,  make_models AS c
WHERE a.make=b.id AND a.model = c.id;
```

While if I join only two tables e.g.: that works but when multiple tables are given it shows query executed successfully but result with 0 rows.

This query is similar to MySQL syntax. Is there something wrong with my query or H2 simply doesn't support it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try below query

```
SELECT a.*, b.name "make", c.name "model"
FROM basicInfo AS a 
JOIN make_models AS b
ON a.make = b.id
JOIN make_models AS c 
ON a.model = c.id;
```

Comment: Ok thanks that worked. But what was the problem because as I know both the queries are same. isn't they?

Comment: You are right, when using two tables it works but with more than two tables you need to use JOIN keyword. Moreover JOIN increases the efficiency of the query, it is an ANSI standard way.

Comment: "*Moreover JOIN increases the efficiency of the query*" - that's not true

Comment: @Rockse The efficiency of the query depends on the amount of data you want to fetch, the columns from which you're fetching data, on the indexes defined for those columns and so on..the performance doesn't depend on the using of JOIN clause.